# Get value from filed if another filed match condition MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

for example i have such structure of document:

```
{
"_id": "1230987",

"Z": [{
    "A": [{
        "B": {
            "C": [{
                "E": "2104331180",
                "D": "boroda.jpg"
            }, {
                "E": "1450987095",
                "D": "small.PNG"
            }]
        },
       
    }],
}]
```

}

How could i get value from field `E` if value in field `D` matches condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `$elemMatch` project:

```
db.collection.find({"Z.A.B.C.D":<condition>},{"Z,A,B,C":{$elemMatch:{D:<condition>} }})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6x4v14rYGEo)

Comment: No elements found :(